# Linking Heroku review apps for separated frontend and backend

Tags: heroku, deployment

So, i plan to implement review apps into our deploy flow. Our application is separated in two codebases and two Heroku instances (frontend and backend). When I open pull request review app is created for that PR, how would I or can I somehow link two review apps for features that bring changes to both frontend and backend and are part of same feature, can I link two review apps from two PR's?

Comment: Did you figure it out @nenad?

Comment: @JonathanCorrin No, I had to merge frontend and backend in one repository and instance to make it work.